Exporting .fbx animation from blender and importing to Unreal Engine deforms mesh
I just got some character assets with a skeleton and mesh and am trying to retarget some animations in blender for the skeleton. I was able to retarget the animation in blender and import it into unreal engine, but there is an issue when I play the animation on a certain skeletal mesh in UE.
The animation works in blender and works perfectly with a male character in Unreal Engine, but when I try to play the animation on female skeletal mesh the breast deforms.


How can I start to debug this problem? What can be the issue here?
I tried to change the orientation of those bones in blender, but no success.
